# MRTK thumbstick input

Tags: mrtk

I’ve been trying to figure how to access thumb-stick input from the controller in `MRTK`.

I’m new to coding and the documentation was just a bit too confusing for me to figure out.

I figured out a pointer click  through the `onPointerClick` methods however I just can’t figure the other inputs.

I’m sure it’s simple, I just need to see an example. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mr_Noonan could you give a bit more detail about what you are trying to do? For example, are you trying to move an object forward based on the direction of the thumbstick? Additionally, could you specify whether you are trying to access thumbstick on xbox controller, or motion controller?

Comment: Hey Julia. Thanks for the response. I’m trying to move an object with the thumbstick (or touchpad) of the MR motion controller. I’ve come up with a pretty bad solution of UI buttons using the pointer methods but the thumbstick or touchpad would play much better!

Answer (score 2):

You can try a script like this:

```
public class ThumbstickMover : InputSystemGlobalListener, IMixedRealityInputHandler<Vector2>
{
    public MixedRealityInputAction moveAction;
    public float speed = 1.0f;

    public void OnInputChanged(InputEventData<Vector2> eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.MixedRealityInputAction == moveAction)
        {
            Vector3 localDelta = speed * (Vector3)eventData.InputData;
            transform.position = transform.position + transform.rotation * localDelta;
        }
    }
}
```

For that to work you'll need to set as `moveAction` an input action that is mapped to one of the thumbsticks. Let me know if you have trouble with that.