# Use of joystick (teletrasport) of Windows Mixed Reality controller in Unity

Tags: mrtk

I'm using MRTK SDK for a Unity project with Windows Moxed Reality Headset.
I need to move gradually in 3D space (forward, backward, up, down, left and right) with a joystick (teletrasport) that is on controller.
I need to make a gradually and fluent movements and not a jump.
Anyone can help me to understand how can I obtain that? 
Thank you
Luca

Answer (score 0):

You can do an approach similar to [the answer from this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019016/mrtk-thumbstick-input).

First, turn off the teleportation system in MRTK so that you don't see the teleport parabola when you press the thumbstick:

Select MRTK object in your scene:

[image]

Then turn off teleport system:

[image]

Finally, attach the following component to your scene content root to move the content around the camera playspace around based on the input. The key idea here is you don't want to move the camera, but instead you want to move the world around you.

```
public class ThumbstickMover : InputSystemGlobalListener, IMixedRealityInputHandler<Vector2>
{
    public MixedRealityInputAction moveAction;
    public float speed = 1.0f;

    public void OnInputChanged(InputEventData<Vector2> eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.MixedRealityInputAction == moveAction)
        {
            Vector3 localDelta = speed * (Vector3)eventData.InputData;
            transform.position = transform.position + transform.rotation * localDelta;
        }
    }
}
```

For that to work you'll need to set as `moveAction` an input action that is mapped to one of the thumbsticks. I used "Teleport Direction".

[image]